# declare files in drupal module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have run pareview.sh to check drupal module. Unfortunately, I got the following error :

FILE: /var/www/drupal-7-pareview/pareview_temp/social_polls.info
FOUND 1 ERROR(S) AFFECTING 1 LINE(S)
4 | ERROR | It's only necessary to declare files[] if they declare a class or interface.

In .info file I write : files[] = social_polls.module

I don't understand the problem.
Thanks . . .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the files[] modulename.module in the .info file
Your .module file doesn't declare any classes or interfaces.
Some files, for example a .test file, would need this.

Answer (score 0):

`files[]` array is used for dynamic-loading of *classes* and *interfaces* into the code registry.

So, you have to include the files which declare the classes or interfaces into the `.info` file.

`.module` files are not needed to be added because they are included automatically, and their functions (mostly [hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/group/hooks/7)) too are included automatically, and executed on certain events.